# How to search Windows registry REG_BINARY for matching data

Tags: windows-registry, search, regedit

How can I use the Windows Registry Editor 'Find' feature (or some other method) to search for a REG_BINARY key who's binary data contains byte sequences that match a specific value?

That is, many REG_BINARY key values contain data formatted in UTF-8 2-byte pairs, with the 1st byte in the pair representing a standard ASCII character and the second byte in the pair being, typically, a null.

I'm trying to find such a binary key which has data referencing a path name.  But I cannot simply search for "Abc" because the binary data is stored as 2-byte pairs: "A" null "b" null "c".  How can I search in such a way as to return/report all binary keys for which the key's data contains a 2-byte string equivalent to "Abc"?

Comment: Try a third-party tool such as Nirsoft's free RegScanner, http://www.nirsoft.net/ , that offers additional search capability.

Comment: That did the trick.  I had seen that when I did my initial research, but skipped right past it for some reason.  Thanks for making me go back and look again.

Answer (score 0):

For the record and those that prefer to "roll their own", you can convert `REG_BINARY` data (`[Byte[]]`) to a string of hex values using the [`[System.BitConverter\]::ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_BitConverter_ToString_System_Byte___) method:

```
$path             = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\'
$LogFontStructure = (Get-ItemProperty $path).iconfont
$HexString        = [System.BitConverter]::ToString( $LogFontStructure )
```

Console Capture:

```
PS C:\> $path             = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\'
>> $LogFontStructure = (Get-ItemProperty $path).iconfont
>> $HexString        = [System.BitConverter]::ToString( $LogFontStructure )
PS C:\>
PS C:\>
PS C:\> $HexString
EB-FF-FF-FF-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-90-01-00-00-00-00-00-01-00-00-05-00-53-00-65-00-67-00-6F-00-65-00-20-00-55-00-49-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
```

Then, to convert your search string to a matching format, use the [`Encoding.GetBytes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_GetBytes_System_String_) method to covert your search text to a byte array, and convert that to a hex string as well:

```
$SearchString = 'Segoe'
$enc          = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$UnicodeBytes = $enc.GetBytes($SearchString)
$HexSearch    = [System.BitConverter]::ToString( $UnicodeBytes )
# Intermediate variables used for clarity. Actual code can use:
# $HexSearch    = [System.BitConverter]::ToString( $enc.GetBytes($SearchString) )
```

Console Capture:

```
PS C:\> $SearchString = 'Segoe'
>> $enc          = [system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
>> $UnicodeBytes = $enc.GetBytes($SearchString)
>> $HexSearch    = [System.BitConverter]::ToString( $UnicodeBytes )
>> # Intermediate variables used for clarity. Actual code can use:
>> # [System.BitConverter]::ToString( $enc.GetBytes($SearchString) )
PS C:\>
PS C:\>
PS C:\> $HexSearch
53-00-65-00-67-00-6F-00-65-00
```

And with both your source and search value in string format, you can use standard string search techniques:

```
PS C:\> $HexString -match $HexSearch
True
PS C:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              53-00-65-00-67-00-6F-00-65-00
```